# Cannot get token when trying to set up emacs slack

Tags: emacs, slack

I installed emacs slack and am trying to set it up using the official way (as described here: https://github.com/yuya373/emacs-slack).  I created the app and got the client id and secret.  I also set the URL to http://localhost:8080 as instructed.  However, for step 3, I get a prompt to install the app and, when I press "Install", I get a "Problem loading page" error: "Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:8080."

The url does show a token, but then I copy it and put it into the configuration, and then start emacs-slack, I get the following error: "failed to request slack-client-counts: not_allowed_token_type".

I also checked the app in my workspace, and, under OAuth & Permissions, it shows an OAuth Access Token; however, using that token gives me the same error message.

Thanks for your help!